# How to ease styling transition of nib UIWebView to a WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm trying to use a WKWebView in my iOS application so that I can take advantage of WKContentController and the ability to add WKUserScript objects to it, as I would like to inject some JavaScript to be used as event listeners.

Since it is currently not possible to instantiate a WKWebView object from nib, I'm wondering, what would be the drawbacks of doing the following:

1. In my nib file, add a UIWebView, adjust it's placement/size/etc.
2. In my ViewController, instantiate a WKWebView using the frame of the UIWebView created from the nib
3. Add the instantiated WKWebView to the subview
4. Remove the nib created UIWebView from the subview and release it
5. Use the WKWebView throughout the rest of the ViewController code

On the controller side, the code would look like:

```
_wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[_uiWebView frame]
                               configuration:configuration];
[self.view addSubview:_wkWebView];

[_uiWebView removeFromSuperview]; //removes the nib UIWebView from the screen
```

What would be the cons to doing this? Memory issues? Weird sizing behavior? Something else?

Am I missing more info that I should give to the WKWebView?

I'd like to know if any red flags come to mind.

Thanks!